# Rails 3 - Using build -error, undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x10338c828

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thread
end
```

When creating a new thread I want to build attachments before saving. I'm doing:

```
@thread.attachments.build(...)
```

but that is erroring with: `` failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x10338c828 ``

Comment: I should add. I first build the thread, which works fine, then I try to build an attachment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `@thread.attachments.build` to create a new unsaved attachment.

If you have `:autosave => true` on your `has_many` (either explicitly or via `accepts_nested_attributes_for`) they will be saved when the parent thread saves.

You may need to set `:inverse_of` on the associations for saving of new records to work correctly:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, :inverse_of => :thread, :autosave => true
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thread, :inverse_of => :attachments
end
```

---

As mentioned by @zetetic: `Thread` is a built in Ruby class and you should not use the same name as a system class in your app.

There are a number of classes in any language which you learn to not use. In such cases I would add something to my classname to make it more descriptive, assuming there's not a better name altogether. Taking a stab at what you app is, you should rename this from `Thread` to something like `Message` or `MessageThread`.

What's happening is that as `Thread` is a core class that is loaded before your app code. There's already a `Thread` class in memory and Rails does not go looking for it in development mode when you first reference it. Rails loads your classes on demand in development by looking for a `thread.rb` file when `Thread` is referenced and not currently loaded.

In production mode, Rails loads all classes at startup and the differing base class (`Object` vs `ActiveRecord::Base`) will result in a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` is a reserved word in Ruby -- I'd suggest renaming your model.

Comment: Nice catch. I'd expect a `TypeError` in production mode but it would probably just not load `app/models/thread.rb` in development mode.

Comment: I get a `TypeError` when creating `class Thread < AR::Base` in the console. How is OP getting Rails to load the model??

Comment: The `Thread` model is not loading at all in development mode. I suspect the OP is using `@thread = Thread.new` which will work against the system `Thread` class. See the addendum in my answer for details.